# Order of incidents

Tags: meaning

Does the expression  ' be accompanied by' imply the order of incidents?
For example, when you say " The establishment of agriculture has been accompanied by the domestication of cattle and other livestock",  does it imply that establishment
was followed by the domestication? Or the other way round?

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd say it usually (but not always) suggests *causality*. In your example, I would assume that the domestication came as a result of agriculture. But often the context (or general knowledge) can override such assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The base meaning of 'be accompanied by' is to do things together, such as:

- two people walking together
- a group of musicians playing together

The implication in 'The establishment of agriculture has been accompanied by the domestication of cattle and other livestock' is that 'establishment' and 'domestication' both happen at the same time.

In reality, it is unlikely that these two actions both started at the same moment, although one could argue that the 'establishment' was the more significant of the two in the text as it gets prime mention.